# $S$ is connected. $A$ is a connected subset of $S$. $B$ is a subset of $S-A$ which is open and closed in $S-A$. Prove that $A\cup B$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness

I am reading "Introduction to Set Thoery and Topology" by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

> Problem 7 in Section 5 in Chapter 4:
> Let $A_1,A_2,B$ be subsets of a topological space $S$.
> Let $B\subset A_1\cap A_2$.
> If $B$ is open in $A_1$ and $A_2$, then $B$ is open in $A_1\cup A_2$.
> If $B$ is closed in $A_1$ and $A_2$, then $B$ is closed in $A_1\cup A_2$.

> Problem 9 in Section 1 in Chapter 5.
> Let $S$ be a connected topological space.
> Let $A$ be a connected subset of $S$.
> Let $B$ be a subset of $A^c=S-A$ which is open and closed in $A^c$.
> Prove that $A\cup B$ is connected.

The author's answer for Problem 9 in Section 1 in Chapter 5 is the following:

> We prove that if $A\cup B=O_1\cup O_2$ and $O_1\cap O_2=\emptyset$ and $O_1$ and $O_2$ are open in $A\cup B$, then $O_1=\emptyset$ or $O_2=\emptyset$.
> Since $A$ is connected, $O_1\cap A=\emptyset$ or $O_2\cap A=\emptyset$.
> So, $O_1\supset A$ and $O_2\subset B$ or $O_2\supset A$ and $O_1\subset B$.
> Without loss of generality, we can assume that $O_1\supset A$ and $O_2\subset B$.
> Since $O_2$ is open and closed in $A\cup B$, $O_2$ is also open and closed in $B$.
> Since $B$ is open and closed in $A^c$, $O_2$ is open and closed in $A^c$.
> By Problem 7 in Section 5 in Chapter 4, $O_2$ is open and closed in $(A\cup B)\cup A^c=S$.
> Since $S$ is connected, $O_2=\emptyset$.

I think the author didn't consider the case in which $A=\emptyset$ and $B=S$ and $O_1=\emptyset$ and $O_2=B=S$.
So, I think the author's answer is not perfect.
Am I right?

Comment: You are right but it is very easy to remedy. Just replace the last sentence by: Since $S$ is connected, $O_2=\varnothing$ or $O_2=S$ (and in the latter case, $O_1=\varnothing$).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much for your answer.